# Drawing a Heart with Sharp Corner in Android

Tags: android, android-canvas

The following question might sound a bit stupid but I guess stupidity has no limit so here it goes. I am drawing a Heart using Canvas in Android and have got no issues in drawing the heart but I am not able to make the heart sharp in the meeting point. My heart looks like [image]

**CODE :**

```
            left_x_moveto = 200;
            left_y_moveto = 45;

            left_x1 = 197;
            left_y1 = -35;
            left_x2 = 60;
            left_y2 = 20;
            left_x3 = 193;
            left_y3 = 130;

            right_x_moveto = 200;
            right_y_moveto = 45;

            right_x1 = 197;
            right_y1 = -35;
            right_x2 = 345;
            right_y2 = 20;
            right_x3 = 193;
            right_y3 = 130;



           heart_outline_paint.setColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.heart_outline_color)); // Change the boundary color
        heart_outline_paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
        heart_outline_paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        path.moveTo(left_x_moveto, left_y_moveto);
        path.cubicTo(left_x1, left_y1, left_x2, left_y2, left_x3, left_y3);

        path.moveTo(right_x_moveto, right_y_moveto);
        path.cubicTo(right_x1, right_y1, right_x2, right_y2, right_x3, right_y3);
        canvas.drawPath(path, heart_outline_paint);
```

**What have I tried so far :**

1. Reducing or increasing the points of `left_x_moveto`,`left_y_moveto` and vice versa but the heart is completely disfigured for which I am unable to find the reason.

When the  `right_x_moveto = 198` and `right_y_moveto = 45`, the heart looks like

[image]

I am not sure why this is happening.

2. Reducing the width of the `heart_outline_paint` would give me what I want but I want the **thickness of the heart** to be the same so reducing the `setStrokeWidth` is not an option.

In short, I want both the curves to **MEET AND MERGE** and not just **MEET**.
Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you try using [Path.close()](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/graphics/Path.html#close())?

Comment: No, where do I close it ? After drawPath ?

Comment: Tried that after drawPath but no use. Thanks anyways for the suggestion.

Comment: OK, then here's a page about drawing hearts (different tecniques): http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/heart.htm

Comment: I had a look at that link before but it didn't help me much, it has more calculations and the way that I follow is pretty simple with just points..

Comment: But your way doesn't produce the desired result. A math function which has been proven working will do.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to perform a couple of this.

1. Close the path via `path.close()`.
2. You need to set the stroke join via `heart_outline_paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);`

A `path` can be closed only if it's drawn continuously. Hence I have modified the code so that `path.close()` can be done properly. Below is the code.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    heart_outline_paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    heart_outline_paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
    path = new Path();

    int left_x_moveto = 200;
    int left_y_moveto = 45;

    int left_x1 = 180;
    int left_y1 = -20;
    int left_x2 = 30;
    int left_y2 = 20;
    int left_x3 = 193;
    int left_y3 = 130;

    int right_x_moveto = 200;
    int right_y_moveto = 45;

    int right_x1 = 214;
    int right_y1 = -20;
    int right_x2 = 375;
    int right_y2 = 20;
    int right_x3 = 193;
    int right_y3 = 130;

    heart_outline_paint.setColor(Color.RED); // Change the boundary color
    heart_outline_paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
    heart_outline_paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    path.moveTo(left_x_moveto, left_y_moveto);
    path.cubicTo(left_x1, left_y1, left_x2, left_y2, left_x3, left_y3);
    path.cubicTo(right_x2, right_y2, right_x1, right_y1, right_x_moveto, right_y_moveto);

    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, heart_outline_paint);
}
```

`Paint.Join.MITER` is the one that does what you want.

> The outer edges of a join meet at a sharp angle

Now this `MITER` join works only when the angle is <= 90 degree. But here, based on the values that you have provided, the angle is 90 degree and hence the `MITER` join doesn't work. I have modified the values to get the following image. The image is not exact, but you need to play around with the value the get the right one.
[image]

You could set the `ROUND` join method to get the following.
[image]

The problem is with `Path.cubicTo()`. It's very hard to get the `MITTER` join work without getting the heart shape squished. So instead of `cubicTo`, I tried with `lineTo` and `arcTo` to create a simple heart. The below is the code for that. You will notice that I have rotated the canvas to 45 degrees and then drew the heart shape. This is purely for convenience, so that the coordinates are simple and does not involve pythagoras theorem.

```
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    heart_outline_paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    heart_outline_paint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
    heart_outline_paint.setColor(Color.RED); // Change the boundary color
    heart_outline_paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
    heart_outline_paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    path = new Path();

    float length = 100;
    float x = canvas.getWidth()/2;
    float y = canvas.getHeight()/2;

    canvas.rotate(45,x,y);

    path.moveTo(x,y);
    path.lineTo(x-length, y);
    path.arcTo(new RectF(x-length-(length/2),y-length,x-(length/2),y),90,180);
    path.arcTo(new RectF(x-length,y-length-(length/2),x,y-(length/2)),180,180);
    path.lineTo(x,y);
    path.close();

    canvas.drawPath(path, heart_outline_paint);
}
```

The final rendered image of this code is below: 
[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking the effort, means a lot !! I will change the points like I need but you've definitely done a great job.. Hats off mate..

Comment: I have used `lineTo` and `arcTo`, to draw a heart shape with the `MITTER` join working as expected. I have put everything in the `onDraw` method, for the sake of simplicity. You should move the `path` and `paint` creation to the constructor.

Comment: Point taken, grateful for the advice.

Comment: perfect one! Thankyou!

Comment: is anyone is up!. what im stuck at that when user move its finger away from first touch  the size of heart should increase and when move close to first touch size should decrease. just like radius, im doing this with rectangle and circle they are working fine but i could not make the heart to go this way,and heart must drawn where i touch my first finger, most of code i found heart draws at top r-l side of screen, please help.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening is that the thickness of the line is being drawn on one side, not on both. In true MS paint fashion:

(The left is what's happening, the right is what you want. Black is the actual position of the line would width be 1px, red is the "padding", the 2nd, 3rd through 15th pixel, `heart_outline_paint.setStrokeWidth(15);`)
[image]

To fix this, try to subtract half the width of the line from the x of right line, and add it to the x of the left line. Doing so will work around this problem, not fix it

Comment: By saying "width of the line" , you are referring that I need to do something with the points that I use for drawing the heart ?

Comment: Yes. What I mean is that in this case `right_x3` should become `right_x3 - (15/2)` (15 because of `heart_outline_paint.setStrokeWidth(15);`) and `left_x3` should become `left_x3 + (15/2)`. As said, it's a workaround not a fix.

Comment: Okay, then I got your code wrong, and then it should be right_x1 and left_x1 that you should subtract and add `(15/2)` to. Though from what I see that may also not produce the correct result, you might have to split the path into two paths.

Comment: Yes I have already tried like you've suggested, but no use. So you are saying that if I use two separate paths then I will be able to achieve it ?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it might be worth a shot. Like, use one path for the left half, and the other for the right half. If that doesn't work, you could attempt to split it into the bottom part and the top part, the top part starting where the two lines on the side are perfectly vertical.

Comment: Tried that too but no luck. Thanks for your suggestions though.